# Semantic ui with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with using Semantic UI and  [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)
I want a selectbox with fulltext search so I find a Select2 and stylized by semantic ui fw. But this two libs make a problem, which i can't resolve. So I ask you for advice. You can see a problem in picture and I attached code.

Html :

```
<select name="roles" id="frm-roles" class="ui dropdown">
  <option value="985">Admin</option>
  <option value="785">Guest</option>
</select>
```

Jquery :

```
$('#frm-roles').select2();
```

[Result on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpW9X.png)

So, why is a selectbox included into another? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you first initialize `dropdown()` and then `select2()` on the same element.

You have to remove the `dropdown()` call from your code (search for something like `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown()` or `$('#frm-roles').dropdown()`) or change your code in another way such that `dropdown()` is not called on this element (`#frm-roles`).